# Xamarin From - Play PowerPoint file

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I play the full `PowerPoint` presentation inside a `Xamarin forms` application?

I've looked into `syncfusion` where you can convert a file to pdf/image to view the latter but is there a way to display the PowerPoint file where you can play the actual slides (e.g. if there's a gif/animation on the slide).

Any leads, please?

Comment: I doubt you can do it in-app unless you write a LOT of code yourself, otherwise you would need to open it in the Powerpoint app

Comment: @Jason that's interesting... thanks